# DFA constructor error, what to do for valid declaration?

Tags: c++, constructor, dfa

I have to write down this project in which I have to make a DFA. I have trouble with figuring how exactly to write my constructor to not get the following error `no matching function for call to 'DFA::DFA(int&, char [2], char [4][2], char&, char [1])'|` . Any help is well welcomed. Here is the code :

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class DFA
{
    int number_of_states;
    char* alphabet;
    char** transition_table;
    char start_state;
    char* final_states;
    public:
        DFA(int,char*,char**,char,char*);
};
DFA::DFA(int snumber_of_states,char* salphabet,char** stransition_table,char    sstart_state, char* sfinal_states)
{
    number_of_states= snumber_of_states;
    int l1=strlen(salphabet);
    alphabet=new char[l1+1];
    for(int i=0;i<l1+1;i++)
    {
        alphabet[i]=salphabet[i];
    }

    transition_table=new char* [number_of_states];
    for(int h=0;h<number_of_states;++h)
    {
        transition_table[h]=new char[l1+1];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<number_of_states;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<l1+1;k++)
            transition_table[j][k]=stransition_table[j][k];
    }

    start_state=sstart_state;

    int l2=strlen(sfinal_states);
    final_states=new char [l2+1];
    for(int r=0;r<l2+1;r++)
    {
        final_states[r]=sfinal_states[r];
    }
}


int main()
{
    char start_state='0';
    char final_states[1]={'3'};
    int number_of_states=4;
    char alphabet[2]={'a','b'};
    char transition_table[4][2]={
                        {'1','1'},
                        {'2','1'},
                        {'0','3'},
                        {'3','-'}
                        };

    DFA automaton(number_of_states,alphabet,transition_table,start_state,final_states);
}
```

Comment: The code you have now is practically all 'C' and very little C++. I highly suggest you use `std::string` instead of `char*`, and `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char**` or `new char[]`. Otherwise you will more than likely have other issues (memory related) that will be much more difficult to figure out than how to issue a call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `no matching function for call to 'DFA::DFA(int&, char [2], char [4][2], char&, char [1])` is due to the fact that a bonafide 2 dimensional array (in this case, a `char[4][2]`) is not the same as a `char**`.  That is the simple explanation (I won't go into why it isn't the same, but that is the issue).

Also, do not try to cast your array to a `char**` to "shut the compiler up" -- that will be a disaster.  Your code also has memory leaks due to the usage of `new[]` without any call to `delete[]`.

Here is a solution in C++ that does away with the usage of so many C-isms in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringArray;

class DFA
{
    int number_of_states;
    std::string alphabet;
    StringArray transition_table;
    char start_state;
    std::string final_states;

public:
    DFA(int, const std::string&, const StringArray&, char, const std::string&);
};

DFA::DFA(int snumber_of_states, const std::string& salphabet, 
         const StringArray& stransition_table, char sstart_state, 
         const std::string& sfinal_states) :
            number_of_states(snumber_of_states), 
            alphabet(salphabet),
            start_state(sstart_state),
            transition_table(stransition_table),
            final_states(sfinal_states) { }

int main()
{
    char start_state='0';
    std::string final_states = "3";
    int number_of_states=4;
    std::string alphabet = "ab";
    StringArray transition_table;
    transition_table.push_back("11");
    transition_table.push_back("21");
    transition_table.push_back("03");
    transition_table.push_back("3-");
    DFA automaton(number_of_states, alphabet, transition_table, start_state,
                  final_states);
}
```

Note the usage of `std::vector` and `std::string`.  The code above is basically what your entire code did using `new[]` and `delete[]`.  The code is brief -- no calls to `strlen`, no loops, no memory leaks, and everything is initialized correctly (pay attention to the `member initialization list` in the constructor of `DFA`).

If you started with this, you will more than likely be further in writing the program to solve your real goal, and that is to write a DFA, not fight with char pointers and dynamically allocated memory.

Edit:  Here is the `main()` program, but using C++ 11's `uniform initialization` syntax:

```
int main()
{
    char start_state='0';
    std::string final_states = "3";
    int number_of_states=4;
    std::string alphabet = "ab";
    StringArray transition_table = {"11", "21", "03", "3-"};
    DFA automaton(number_of_states, alphabet, transition_table, start_state, 
                  final_states);
}
```

So the code now becomes even shorter than the first version.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you not not use uniform initialization for the StringArray?

Comment: @soandos - I could have, but wanted the solution to work for pre-C++ 11 compilers.

Comment: Updated answer to add `initialization syntax` version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your third parameter, which does not have the needed type.

Quoting from the error message from the compiler (gcc 4.9):

> prog.cpp:14:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘char [4][2]’ to ‘char**’
>   prog.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr DFA::DFA(const DFA&)

To fix the problem you have, just change the lines so be:

> DFA(int,char*,char[4][2],char,char*);

and

> DFA::DFA(int snumber_of_states,char* salphabet, char stransition_table[4][2],char    sstart_state, char* sfinal_states)

Note that while this makes your code compile and run without crashing, it is not a good way to write this in c++. This is simply C with one simple constructor.